# explain simple return keyword

Tags: javascript, return-value, map-function

So i've come up with a basic solution to a problem which returns an array:

```
 function doubleAll(numbers) {
          var result = []

          numbers.map(function(val, i){
            result.push(val*2);
          })

          return result
    }
```

however the official solution simply uses a double return statment and I'm trying to understand the order of opperations and how it is actually working.

```
function doubleAll(numbers) {
      return numbers.map(function double(num) {
        return num * 2
      })
    }
```

I'm kind of interested in what is happening behind the scenes and the differences between the two ways of doing it.

Comment: [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: `.map()` is not `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

So in your example:

```
function doubleAll(numbers) {      
      return numbers.map(function double(num) {
        return num * 2
      }) //returns array 
}
```

and

```
 function doubleAll(numbers) {
          var result = [];
          numbers.map(function(val, i){
            result.push(val*2); //pushing value into result array
          });
          return result;
 }
```

In second example the resource is getting wasted since map returns an array and it never used, which can still be achieved using `forEach` method without wasting resource:

```
function doubleAll(numbers) {
  var result = [];
  numbers.forEach(function(val, i){
    result.push(val*2); //pushing value into result array
  });
  return result;
}
```

This polyfill will add more clarity about `.map`:
Ref from MDN:

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.19
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19
if (!Array.prototype.map) {

  Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, A, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(' this is null or not defined');
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| 
    //    value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
    //    method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array(len) 
    //    where Array is the standard built-in constructor with that name and 
    //    len is the value of len.
    A = new Array(len);

    // 7. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 8. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue, mappedValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal 
      //    method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
        //    method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Let mappedValue be the result of calling the Call internal 
        //     method of callback with T as the this value and argument 
        //     list containing kValue, k, and O.
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);

        // iii. Call the DefineOwnProperty internal method of A with arguments
        // Pk, Property Descriptor
        // { Value: mappedValue,
        //   Writable: true,
        //   Enumerable: true,
        //   Configurable: true },
        // and false.

        // In browsers that support Object.defineProperty, use the following:
        // Object.defineProperty(A, k, {
        //   value: mappedValue,
        //   writable: true,
        //   enumerable: true,
        //   configurable: true
        // });

        // For best browser support, use the following:
        A[k] = mappedValue;
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }

    // 9. return A
    return A;
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks, what exactly is a polyfill and what does it show me?

Comment: Polyfill is a piece of code (or plugin) which works as if it is a part of native code when those features doesn't available.. Specially in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method of an array will execute a callback on each member of the array and returns the resulting array.

```
function doubleAll(numbers) {      
      return numbers.map(function double(num) {
        return num * 2
      }) //returns an array whose members have each been passed to double(num)
}
```

In this case doubleAll() is returning the results of numbers.map(), which is an array whose members have been mutated by the callback function double(num).